# How to dismiss all popups at the platform resume?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

In my application, I have this alert:

```
let confirm = this.alertCtrl.create({
                    title: 'Blabla',
                    message: 'blablabla',
                    buttons: [button1, button2, button3],
                    enableBackdropDismiss: false
                });
                confirm.present();
```

Also, when the application is resumed, the application should redirect to login page. No problem in making that work.

The problem comes, when I open the popup and resume the application. The application does redirect correctly, but the popup remains opened.

Is there a solution to programatically close all the popups opened? The resume function is called from app.component:

```
this.platform.resume.subscribe(() => {});
```

For this reason I cannot call confirm variable and close this popup.

Comment: You can subscribe to the same event from different places. So, you can call `this.platform.resume.subscribe(() => {});` from the component where your `confirm` variable is accessible.

Comment: Ok, You're right, that a solution! Problem is that I have to do that each time I open an alert in my application...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subscribe to the same event from different places. So, you can call `this.platform.resume.subscribe(() => {});` from the component where your `confirm` variable is accessible.

Comment: Why don't you make a provider for alert. In that provider only once you will write the subscribe() method. And whenever you have to create an alert you will do it using that provider.

Answer (score 2):

[Sabari's method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43316758/how-to-dismiss-all-popups-at-the-platform-resume/43318081#43318081) works! I am currently implementing methods in my components to allow the app to go back in its steps when the user presses the device's Back button, but instances of AlertController, AlertSheetController and similar were problematic.

The only change that I made in comparison to his solution was to implement a boolean called logoutStarted that changed to true whenever AlertController presented an alert.

```
if (this.alerts.length > 0 || this.logoutStarted) { 
        this.alerts.forEach(i => {
            i.dismiss();
            this.alerts = [];
            this.logoutStarted = false;
        });
      }
```

Doing this, I was able to shut down the alert from the method:

```
this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(() =>{}
```

Answer (score 1):

Open the alerts from common page(provider) by calling presentAlert() method.

And in onresume subscription, call the dismissAlert() method to close all opened alerts.

```
alerts: Alert[] = [];

 presentAlert() {
        let confirm = this.alertCtrl.create({
            title: 'Blabla',
            message: 'blablabla',
            buttons: [button1, button2, button3],
            enableBackdropDismiss: false
        });
        this.alerts.push(confirm);
        confirm.present();
    }

    dismissAlert() {
        console.log('Dismissed alert');
        if (this.alerts.length) {
            this.alerts.forEach(e => {
                e.dismiss();
            });
        }
        this.alerts = [];
    }
```